# how to make a table fit into a certain size

Tags: html, css

I have this table which comes out bigger than it's background box.

[image]

How can i make the table fit this bg box?

[image]

---

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2LLfk4j/)

---

### **CODE SNIPPET:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="">
  <div class="content-background" style="background-color: #4285f4;   height: 398px;   position: absolute;   width: 100%;   top: 60px; z-index: -1;"></div>
  <div class="appbar-container" style="background-color: #4285f4;   color: #fff;   height: auto; width: 100%;">
    <div class="appbar-top" style="padding-left: 80px; overflow: hidden;"><span class="" style="line-height: 64px; font-size: 20px;" itemprop="title">Failures in 1.0.705</span>
      <p style="font-weight: 300; display: inline-block; float: right; margin: 10px; padding-right: 24px;">save date: 06:44:41 03-Sep-02016</p>
    </div>
  </div><span class="primary-container"><div class="page-width-container" style="float: left;   margin-left: 128px;   width: 832px; background-color: #fff;   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.26);   padding: 64px; position: relative;"><span class="primary-article" role="main"><span><table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="1" style="width:100%"><th style="width:70%">Error</th><th>Percent (% from total)</th><tr><td rowspan="2">com.github.rholder.retry.RetryException: Retrying failed to complete successfully after 3 attempts.  previous error was: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Failed to handle request </td><td>59.35% ( 3.65% )</td></tr><tr></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">com.github.rholder.retry.RetryException: Retrying failed to complete successfully after 3 attempts.  previous error was: linqmap.p2p.NoAvailableServerException: Could not find server to send to for Routing.[_all_] (resgistry: GeoRegistryClientConfig)  stack:linqmap.p2p.NoAvailableServerException: Could not find server to send to for Routing.[_all_] (resgistry: GeoRegistryClientConfig)
    at linqmap.p2p.impl.ClientP2PRegistryAccess.getServers(ClientP2PRegistryAccess.java:409)
```

Comment: please provide some fiddle

Comment: can you provide the code online?

Comment: added fiddle. thanks

Comment: Man honestly, how hard is it to provide your code here in SO in a code snippet? [**Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry, i did now. thanks

Comment: Do you have any more question? Could you accept my answer otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.primary-article {
   word-break: break-all; 
}
```

will solve your problem.
It's a general problem with CSS and will happen when a word is too long (meaning without a space between). Then it will break out of it's container. To avoid this you can force breaking of words or you can set the container to overflow:hidden; to cut the overflowing text.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77w36oqd/

EDIT: Actually in your case not only the content of the `<td>` breaks out, but also other elements like `<h3>` in the .primary-article container. So you can force word breaking for the whole container.